# Oh My Zsh Theme only works after reloading

Tags: git, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I am creating a custom zsh theme. Below is the code from the theme file. That part that I am concerned with is the part modifying the **git_branch** variable.

```
if [[ $USER = "vivek" ]]; then
    local user='%{$terminfo[bold]$fg[red]%}vivek%{$reset_color%}'
else
    local user='%{$terminfo[bold]$fg[green]%}tamil%{$reset_color%}'
fi

local current_dir='%{$terminfo[bold]$fg[blue]%} %~%{$reset_color%}'

local git_branch=''
if [[ -d .git ]]; then
    git_branch='some text $(git_prompt_info)%{$reset_color%}'
fi

PROMPT="╭─${user} ${current_dir} ${git_branch}
╰─%B$%b "
RPS1="${return_code}"

ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_PREFIX="%{$fg[yellow]%}‹"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_SUFFIX="› %{$reset_color%}"
```

For some reason the **git_branch** only gets updated if I call zsh when I am in a directory with git initialized. It doesn't get reloaded automatically when I switch directories or when I first open zsh shell.

Can someone help explain why this is happening?